# Read HttpServletResponse headers and body in Apache Camel jetty component

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, apache-camel, proxy-server

I am trying to create an HTTP proxy server using Apache Camel Jetty Component. Following is my code -

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:8080?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
        .process(new Processor() {

            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                HttpServletRequest req = exchange.getIn().getBody(
                        HttpServletRequest.class);
            Enumeration<String> headers = request.getHeaderNames();
            while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
                String headerName = headers.nextElement();
                String headerValue = request.getHeader(headerName);
            }
            InputStream stream = request.getInputStream();
            int bytesRead;
            String line = "";
            byte b[] = new byte[1024];
            while ((bytesRead = stream.read(b)) != -1) {
                line = line + new String(b, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        })
        .to("http://www.google.com:80?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
        .process(new Processor() {

            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

                HttpServletResponse res = exchange.getIn().getBody(
                        HttpServletResponse.class);


});
```

I am able to read HttpServletRequest headers and data. However, I am not able to read HttpServletResponse data as there is no getInputStream() method in HttpServletResponse. I found some post related to this problem but they said that either I have to subclass HttpServletResponse or create a filter. But in apache camel, I am not directly interacting with HttpServletResponse class so how I can sub class it or create a filter

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: You know that there is a Proxy implementation available in Jetty itself, right?

Comment: I know that but how it can solve my problem. May be Apache camel would be using this implementation internally.

Comment: based on your code example and the issues you are hitting, I can say with high level of confidence that Apache Camel is not using the Jetty Proxy implementation.